# Open Power Point chart data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a macro to clean up the Excel sheets behind charts in power point so that only the data being used in the chart is there, and there are no formulas.

I've pieced together this, which works when I open the chart data in Excel, but I'm hoping I can create a macro that cycles through each chart in the workbook and opens the chart data in Excel for me, so I can perform the following on each.

```
Sub ChartCleaningPP()

'Paste values of table

    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Dim Cell As Range

'clear other cells

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If Intersect(Cell, Selection) Is Nothing Then
Cell.Clear
End If
Next Cell

'remove hidden

For lp = 256 To 1 Step -1
If Columns(lp).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Columns(lp).EntireColumn.Delete Else
Next
For lp = 65536 To 1 Step -1
If Rows(lp).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then Rows(lp).EntireRow.Delete Else
Next

'close window

ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ChangeCharts()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myChart As ChartObject

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each myChart In ws.ChartObjects
        'your code here
        'i.e Call ChartCleaningPP
        Next myChart
    Next ws
End Sub
```

EDIT: (Run Excel Makro from PP)
Need to activate MS Excel Libraries in PP.

```
Sub RunExcelMakro()
Dim wk As Object
Dim Path As String
CreateObject ("Excel.Application")
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True

Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\F\1.xlsm" 'Edit Path
Set wk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path)

xlApp.Run "YourMakro"

xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub M1()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim Path As String

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In sld.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                With sh.LinkFormat
                    Path = .SourceFullName
                    xlApp.Workbooks.Open Path

                End With
            End If
        Next sh
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. I think it would have worked in an Excel sheet, but I need it for a PowerPoint. It needs to get the Excel sheets behind the PowerPoint charts open before my code will work.

Comment: Try it now. Is it what you want now?

Comment: If you right click a PowerPoint chart, you can select edit data> edit data in excel, and that opens the excel file I need opened. I don't know the file path of these. The thing I want is a macro that opens each of them in the PowerPoint, 100 Excel sheets behind 100 charts, so that I can run the code on each.

Comment: try my edit, if it works the charts are linked excel object, otherwise they are just normal charts (yea they can have an excel sheet for there data but thats not the same)and as far as i know there is no way to do it with vba.

Comment: You could just open one up and see if they are in the same folder, then you could cycle trough them.

Comment: Yeah they are just normal charts. Makes sense; I looked for a way to do this pretty extensively and couldn't find it. Thanks for your help!